# Apache accessing /media/ instead of DocumentRoot/media

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

My Apache config has the following statements :

```
    DocumentRoot /home/x/public/
    <Location />
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from all
      Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
    </Location>
```

There is a directory /media under /home/x/public/

```
    RewriteRule ^(/media/.+) $1 [L]
```

Media files should be left untouched and served by Apache - other requests are redirected to a Ruby on Rails Proxy server.

Whenever I try to access a file under /media through a browser, Apache tries to serve /media/file (on the filestystem root dir) instead of /home/x/public/media/file

If I rename /media into /medias, the file /home/x/public/media/file is served correctly.

How can I prevent this behaviour ?

Edit : adding mod_rewrite logs :

If "mv /media/ /medias" :

```
applying pattern '^(/media/.+)' to uri '/media/css/TableTools.css'
rewrite '/media/css/TableTools.css' -> '/media/css/TableTools.css'
local path result: /media/css/TableTools.css
prefixed with document_root to /home/x/public/media/css/TableTools.css
go-ahead with /home/x/public/media/css/TableTools.css [OK]
```

If "mv /medias /media" :

```
applying pattern '^(/media/.+)' to uri '/media/css/TableTools.css'
rewrite '/media/css/TableTools.css' -> '/media/css/TableTools.css'
local path result: /media/css/TableTools.css
go-ahead with /media/css/TableTools.css [OK]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (n.b. emphasis is mine):

> The Substitution of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the
>   original URL-path that was matched by Pattern. The Substitution may be
>   a:
>
> **file-system path**
>
> Designates the location on the file-system of the
>   resource to be delivered to the client. Substitutions are only treated
>   as a file-system path when *the rule is configured in server
>   (virtualhost) context and the first component of the path in the
>   substitution is exists in the file-system*

Because "/media" exists in the filesystem, you're hitting this interpretation of the "Substitution" string. A better way to do what you want would be

```
RewriteRule ^(/media/.+) - [L]
```

where the `-` means "do not rewrite at all, only apply the flags attached to the RewriteRule" - so in this case the `[L]` flag will be applied and mod_rewrite will not attempt to use any other rules on this request.